# In blender 3D, is it possible to save a keyframe of a mesh that has a soft body property

Tags: 3d, blender

I am using blender 3D right now, and i 'baked' a cloth soft body. However, i want just one keyframe of the cloth.
In this case, i make curtains for a window and made it a cloth. I baked it to just how i want the cloth to look, but for my animation i want a single still cloth object to be placed. I want the curtains to be one still cloth-looking object for the whole animation.

So is there a way that i can get that mesh to stay in that one position for the entire animation? 
If so, then how do i do it?

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

1. In 3d view, select the object in the desired animation frame.
2. Press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and convert it to mesh.

If I remember correctly, this shold keep the geometry, but remove the animation.

Comment: Hi Adamsan, you remebered correctly, it did the trick for me! Thanks a lot!!